# What's the right way to have a thread-safe lazy-initialized possibly mutable value in Rust?

Tags: rust, synchronization, thread-safety, lazy-initialization

I have a struct that contains a field that is rather expensive to initialize, so I want to be able to do so lazily. However, this may be necessary in a method that takes `&self`. The field also needs to be able to modified once it is initialized, but this will only occur in methods that take `&mut self`.

What is the correct (as in idiomatic, as well as in thread-safe) way to do this in Rust? It seems to me that it would be trivial with either of the two constraints:

- If it only needed to be lazily initialized, and not mutated, I could simply use [`lazy-init`](https://github.com/khuey/lazy-init)'s `Lazy<T>` type.
- If it only needed to be mutable and not lazy, then I could just use a normal field (obviously).

However, I'm not quite sure what to do with both in place. [`RwLock`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.RwLock.html) seems relevant, but it appears that there is considerable trickiness to thread-safe lazy initialization given what I've seen of `lazy-init`'s source, so I am hesitant to roll my own solution based on it.

Comment: Try `Lazy<RwLock<T>>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest solution is `RwLock<Option<T>>`.

> However, I'm not quite sure what to do with both in place. `RwLock` seems relevant, but it appears that there is considerable trickiness to thread-safe lazy initialization given what I've seen of `lazy-init`'s source, so I am hesitant to roll my own solution based on it.

`lazy-init` uses tricky code because it guarantees lock-free access after creation. Lock-free is always a bit trickier.

Note that in Rust it's easy to tell whether something is tricky or not: tricky means using an `unsafe` block. Since you can use `RwLock<Option<T>>` without any unsafe block there is nothing for you to worry about.

---

A variant to `RwLock<Option<T>>` may be necessary if you want to capture a closure for initialization *once*, rather than have to pass it at each potential initialization call-site.

In this case, you'll need something like `RwLock<SimpleLazy<T>>` where:

```
enum SimpleLazy<T> {
    Initialized(T),
    Uninitialized(Box<FnOnce() -> T>),
}
```

You don't have to worry about making `SimpleLazy<T>` `Sync` as `RwLock` will take care of that for you.